# Trouble rewriting a recursive function in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Hi All so i have the following function which works on my local machine. However i now want to translate it over to airflow and I'm not sure how recursive functions work in airflow?
Could anyone offer any guidance on the best way to get this into a task in airflow? Im also aware that the data frame I'm calling will have to be pulled from a table in BQ as Data frame cant persist over various task in airflow.

**Python code local version**

```py
manufacturers = {'G4F0': 'FLN', 'G4F1': 'FLN', 'G4F9': 'FLN', 'G4K0': 'HWL', 'E6S1': 'LPG', 'E6S2': 'LPG'}
       
meter_models = {'G4F0': {'1': 'G4SZV-1', '2': 'G4SZV-2'},
                'G4F9': {'': 'G4SZV-1'},
                'G4F1': {'': 'G4SDZV-2'},
                'G4K0': {'': 'BK-G4E'},
                'E6S1': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                'E6S2': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                }

def map_manufacturer_model(s):
    s = str(s)
    model = ''
    try:
        manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
        for k, m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
            if s[-4:].startswith(k):
                model = m
                break
    except KeyError:
        manufacturer = ''

    return pd.Series({'New Meter Manufacturer': manufacturer,
                      'New Meter Model': model
                      })


df[['New Meter Manufacturer', 'New Meter Model']] = df['New Serial Number'].apply(map_manufacturer_model)
```

**Airflow version**

```
def map_manufacturer_model(s):
# Download query results.
query_string = """
SELECT * FROM `bq_table`
"""

gas_data = (
    bqclient.query(query_string)
        .result()
        .to_dataframe(
        # Optionally, explicitly request to use the BigQuery Storage API. As of
        # google-cloud-bigquery version 1.26.0 and above, the BigQuery Storage
        # API is used by default.
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    )
)

manufacturers = {'G4F0': 'FLN', 'G4F1': 'FLN', 'G4F9': 'FLN', 'G4K0': 'HWL', 'E6S1': 'LPG', 'E6S2': 'LPG'}

meter_models = {'G4F0': {'1': 'G4SZV-1', '2': 'G4SZV-2'},
                'G4F9': {'': 'G4SZV-1'},
                'G4F1': {'': 'G4SDZV-2'},
                'G4K0': {'': 'BK-G4E'},
                'E6S1': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                'E6S2': {'': 'E6VG470'},
                }

s = str(s)
model = ''
try:
    manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
    for k, m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
        if s[-4:].startswith(k):
            model = m
            break
except KeyError:
    manufacturer = ''

return pd.Series({'New Meter Manufacturer': manufacturer,
                  'New Meter Model': model
                  })

gas_data[['New Meter Manufacturer', 'New Meter Model']] = gas_data['New Serial Number'].apply(
            map_manufacturer_model)


with models.DAG('test_dag',
                schedule_interval='0 8 * * *',
                default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    
    map_manufacturer_model_function = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='map_manufacturer_model_function',
        python_callable=map_manufacturer_model
    )
```

Comment: Use `PythonOperator`, refer to this - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/11/data-engineering-101-getting-started-with-python-operator-in-apache-airflow/

Comment: As @Vikramsinh Shinde has mentioned in the comments, to run Python code in Airflow, [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonoperator) has to be used. Also, since you have attached the `BigQuery` tag, can you please add more details about where BigQuery will fall in your workflow? Are you trying to read data from BigQuery, convert it into a dataframe then apply the transformation function on it? If so, do you need help in reading data from BigQuery as part of your Python code?

Comment: I can't see any recursion here.

Comment: In airflow, the python code is pulling data from a table in BQ as data frames dont persist in code with multiple functions that call a single dataframe.

Comment: @MizanurChoudhury Can you clarify if your requirement is to pass dataframes across functions in the PythonOperator or to pass them across tasks?

Comment: so i'm using bigquery tables to pass information between functions and tasks (I think, i'm still learning how to use dataframes in airflow across tasks and functions! Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this was returning errors was because of the following:

When you actually call the PythonOperator you are not passing in the s argument. You can add the op_kwargs, to the arguments passed as part of the call as below:

```
map_manufacturer_model_function = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='map_manufacturer_model_function',
        python_callable=map_manufacturer_model,
        op_kwargs={'s':'stringValue'}
    )
```

See the python operator example here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html